# Expandable lists under tabs

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm building an UWP app where I have two lists of items that are similar but different entities (highlighted in green), then there is a bar with several controls to navigate/operate those lists (highlighted in purple). And then there are tabs that are used to switch between those two lists (highlighted in red).

A list is collapsed by default but user can expand/collapse it by pressing arrow icon at the bottom of a list. When the list is expanded it covers other content above it (highlighted in orange) but not below.

User is able to switch between lists using tabs irregardless of its state (collapsed or expanded). Please see wireframe below for more details.

What's the best way to do that?

Also, all depicted controls are already within a Pivot control (highlighted in pink).

[Wireframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThRqV.png)

Comment: How did you achieve your expandable `ListView`? Can you please post your xaml code? Is your `ListView` expanded in a popup control?

Comment: Well, I didn't achieve that yet. That's what I'm trying to find out here. Will post an answer if no one else will, providing that I'll be able to figure it out.

Comment: Oh, I see...You just collapsed the `ListView`, then you can try to set `Canvas.ZIndex="1"` to your content grid and `Canvas.ZIndex="0"` to your `ListView`.